# Check the last time the SD card was inserted/used on Android phone

Tags: sd-card

I have obviously not been paying attention to the fact that I no longer have an SD card in my Samsung Galaxy S7, that I know used to be there. I just recently discovered that it is missing, and now I am paranoid that someone has removed it in order to look at its contents.

I am hoping that there is some way to check the records in the phone and see the last time an SD card was inserted, or to see a timestamp of when it was last used, to help narrow down when it went missing.

Comment: check notification history https://www.guidingtech.com/53398/view-android-notifications-history

Comment: thank you. I did try this, but there is no settings widget that I can select from. The closest thing I can find is going to the Novo Launcher Activity widget, and going to its settings, where I can scroll down past about 150 other settings Activity options until I can chose notification log. However this only shows notifications until about 2 days in the past.

Comment: in /data/system/storage.xml is a creation date not sure if this is resetted when sdcard is missing

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I've been struggling to figure out how to read this folder for the past few days. I downloaded an app called FX File Explorer to access /data/system/storage.xml but there is no way to read the folder or download it. Do I need to go about rooting my phone to view this? Or could you recommend an app that works?

Comment: sorry, forget it. yes, only with root access, but its not worth it. there is nothing helpful in this file. sorry for misleading. wait for someone how know answer, i just spread "Gefährliches Halbwissen"